# inline !important css not working on <table>

Tags: html, css

I have an issue. I have tried the style 'table style="width:200px!important;"' as inline but still somehow table is of 742 px
what could be the reason of it as we know inline important override all other styles. in td I am just printing 1,2,3 garbage smallest values but still no luck.

```
   <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($this->getHeader()) ?></span></strong>

    <?php $products = $this->getCollection(); ?>
    <?php if (0 < $products->getSize()) { ?>
        <table style="width:200px !important;">

            <tr>
                <?php 
                $i=0;
                foreach ($products as $p) { ?>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">                        
                        1                        
                    </td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>


        </table>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you provide little bit more code or fiddle or something?

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/ — A good code example would be pure HTML with the minimum number of rows to reproduce the problem. It wouldn't include any PHP since that doesn't have any effect on the rendering in the browser.

Comment: Can you share the resulting html code ? How many columns are there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!important` will force the value of that property to be `200px`.

It won't force the table to conform to that width.

The default [table layout model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout) is `auto` and will adapt the table to fit its contents, no matter what `width` you specify.

> If the 'table' or 'inline-table' element has 'width: auto', the used width is the greater of the table's containing block width, CAPMIN, and MIN.

You need to switch to the `fixed` layout model if you want to lock a table width below its natural width.